How to add invocation id to logs for a FastAPI using Azure Functions
I am trying to log the activities that are happening to each azure function invocation. Here is a sample log:
[2024-10-16T07:02:36.887Z] Executing 'Functions.http_app_func' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=**7c00101e-1073-41f8-bc17-8fe3473d030c**)
[2024-10-16T07:02:36.921Z] 2024-10-16 07:02:36,913 - DEBUG - search.product.Start
[2024-10-16T07:02:36.923Z] 2024-10-16 07:02:36,913 - DEBUG - product.search_name.Start

I want to add the invocation id to my logs so that I can filter using invocation id in my log aggregator.
Here is my function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func

from src import app as fastapi_app

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(
    app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


Here is my fastAPI:
import json
from typing import Dict, List, Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI(title="Hybrid Search", version="1.0.0")

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

@app.post("/search/text")
def search(product_name: str):
    # Get the invocation ID from the request state
    logger.debug(f"__init__.search.Start, Invocation ID.}")
    logger.debug(f"__init__.search.End, Invocation ID.}")

I tried resolving the context from func
import azure.functions as func
invocation_id = func.Context.invocation_id

But I am not getting the invocation_id.

Check if below solution helps.

In case of azure.functions.AsgiFunctionApp or azure.function.AsgiMiddleware, the context's thread_local_storage and the parent thread's invocation_id are actually included in the scope.
You can fetch the Invocation_ID  using below code:

Thanks for the code @pootietangus.

fastapi code snippet:
import logging
import fastapi
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi import Request, Body

# FastAPI app setup
app = fastapi.FastAPI()

# Setup logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Add CORS middleware
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

# Define a POST route to perform search (for demonstration)
@app.post("/search/text")
def search(product_name: str,request: Request):
    result = {"message": f"Results for {product_name}"}
    thread_local_storage = request.scope.get("azure_functions.thread_local_storage")
    if thread_local_storage is not None:
        parent_invocation_id = request.scope.get("azure_functions.invocation_id")
        thread_local_storage.invocation_id = parent_invocation_id
    logging.info("Hello world! The Invocation Id is: "+thread_local_storage.invocation_id) # remember print() doesn't work
    return result

function_app.py:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from src import app as fastapi_app

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

Run the function as below:

Able to fetch the Invocation ID in the Console logs:
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.6280 Commit hash: N/A +421f0144b42047aa289ce691dc6db4fc8b6143e6 (64-bit)       
Function Runtime Version: 4.834.3.22875

[2024-10-17T06:06:04.211Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        http_app_func: [GET,POST,DELETE,HEAD,PATCH,PUT,OPTIONS] http://localhost:7071//{*route}

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-10-17T06:06:09.114Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.       
[2024-10-17T06:06:15.813Z] Executing 'Functions.http_app_func' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=4cbbdcb8-6b89-46e6-8ecb-cdae5c7ddfa1)
[2024-10-17T06:06:15.936Z] Hello world! The Invocation Id is: 4cbbdcb8-6b89-46e6-8ecb-cdae5c7ddfa1
[2024-10-17T06:06:16.047Z] Executed 'Functions.http_app_func' (Succeeded, Id=4cbbdcb8-6b89-46e6-8ecb-cdae5c7ddfa1, Duration=320ms)


